# Bearer Token "audience" claim is invalid

Tags: authentication, jmeter, token

I am new to JMeter so appreciate any help. I have created a test to generate a bearer token successfully. However, when I try to use this token to access an API end point, I get an error

WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'xxxxxx' is invalid"

After decoding the token, I see this is the application_id but I understand it needs to be the intended recipient, based on the below:

"aud: Identifies the intended recipient of the token. In id_tokens, the audience is your app's Application ID, assigned to your app in the Azure portal. Your app should validate this value, and reject the token if the value does not match."

1. What's the difference between id_token and access_token?
2. How do I fix this and input the intended recipient in my test? What format is this, URL, ID, etc?

[current JMeter configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09taE.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per [OAuth documentation](https://oauth.net/id-tokens-vs-access-tokens/):

> - ID tokens are meant to be read by the OAuth client. Access tokens are meant to be read by the resource server.
> - ID tokens are JWTs. Access tokens can be JWTs but may also be a random string.
> - ID tokens should never be sent to an API. Access tokens should never be read by the client.

So it looks like you've correlated the wrong token or the property holding it is not updated somewhere somehow

You can check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-oauth) for more information. You may also find [atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx](https://github.com/aboyfromipanema/jmeter-oauth/blob/main/atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx) example useful, most probably it won't work for particular your application Azure AD integration but you can get some ideas from there.